# LDAP Authentication not working in Graphite

Tags: python3, django

I have Installed Graphite in RHEL7 server. I have done the LDAP configuration in Graphite local_settings.py

```
## LDAP / ActiveDirectory authentication setup
USE_LDAP_AUTH = True
LDAP_SERVER = "ldap-test.de.com"
LDAP_PORT = 389
#LDAP_USE_TLS = True

## Manual URI / query setup
LDAP_URI = "ldap://ldap-test.de.com:389"
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE = "ou=test,dc=test"
LDAP_BASE_USER = "uid=test,ou=test1,cn=test2"
LDAP_BASE_PASS = "safdsfeefd"
LDAP_USER_QUERY = "(sAMAccountName=%s)"  #For Active Directory use "(sAMAccountName=%s)"

# User DN template to use for binding (and authentication) against the
# LDAP server. %(username) is replaced with the username supplied at
# graphite login.
LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "cn=% (username),ou=test1,dc=test"

# If you want to further customize the ldap connection options you should
# directly use ldap.set_option to set the ldap module's global options.
# For example:
#
#import ldap
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW) # Use #ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND to force TLS
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0) # Enable for Active Directory
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, "/etc/ssl/ca")
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE, "/etc/ssl/mycert.pem")
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, "/etc/ssl/mykey.pem")
#ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 65535) # To enable verbose debugging
# See http://www.python-ldap.org/ for further details on these options.
```

I also reastarted the graphite service by `service uwsgi restart`. When I tried to login , it throws

> "Authentication Attempt Failed,please make sure you entered your login
>   and password correctly"

In logs also I'm unable to find the error messages. How to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have the Python LDAP modules installed (whatever Graphite documents as required)? Does a command-line ldapsearch with these same parameters connect successfully? Is your LDAP server perhaps configured to require TLS (ldaps)? And... did you just post the real username/password for your company's LDAP server?

Comment: I have installed the Python LDAP module mentioned in Graphite documentation. I also tried to query the LDAP through python ldap module and it works.

Comment: @grawity, need your help to fix this issue